# Don't show submenu in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

{#  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!menu.html.twig/8
    menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
    items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
      attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
      below: The menu item child items.
      title: The menu link title.
      url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
      localized_options: Menu link localized options.

## }

{# All menu and submenu items #}

  {% for item in items %}

      {# Menu with submenu #}

          {% if item.below %}
- {{ item.title }} 
                      
                          {# Menu -> Submenu #}

                          {% for item in item.below %}

                              {% include "@nature/snippet/menu-infinite-child.html.twig" with { 'item': item } %}

                          {% endfor %}

{# Menu without submenu #}

        {% else %}

    {# Menu - Link #}

            {% if item.title == 'Home' %}

{{ item.title }} 

            {% endif %}

            {% if item.title == 'About' %}

{{ item.title }} 

            {% endif %}

            {% if item.title == 'Pages' %}

{{ item.title }} 

            {% endif %}

            {% if item.title == 'Blogs' %}

{{ item.title }} 

            {% endif %} 

            {% if item.title == 'Parfolio' %}

{{ item.title }} 

            {% endif %}

            {% if item.title == 'Contact' %}

{{ item.title }} 

            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

the above code for menu--mani.html.twig,the submenu not printed in drupal 8

thank in advance

Comment: Please use proper code formatting, it's really hard to read the code samples. We could also use some more explanation as to what you are trying to do, please! Also the referenced `menu-infinite-child.html.twig` template seems to be left out and is potentially very important in answering your question.

Comment: I just want to show sub menu for any menu  parent  items  in drupal 8,Thanks for your response

Comment: Based on that it sounds like you'd just want to change the "Initial menu level" setting on your menu block to 2, and increase the "Maximum number of menu levels to display". If that helps you I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Cottser,Now it's show sub menu when i am set initial menu level 1 and maximum unlimited in configuration of block

Comment: So does that solve your issue or not?

Comment: yes it solve my issue now show sub menu properly

Answer (score 1):

You should go to configuration of main Navigation block, and change "Maximum number of menu levels to display" to be unlimited instead of only one.